# xUnit 'Collection Fixtures' equivalent for MSTest?

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, mstest, xunit

I'm wondering if there is a ["Collection Fixtures"](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) equivalent for the MSTest framework?

> **Collection Fixtures**
> *When to use*: when you want to create a single test
> context and share it among tests in several test classes, and have it
> cleaned up after all the tests in the test classes have finished.

I have some MSTest integration tests that all need access to some common services/access tokens/etc used in all the tests. In MSTest, every test class is recreated for each test so it gets expensive to load all that information for each test case.

In xUnit I can just use collection fixtures to store all the shared services in a single test context, but in MSTest, I don't see how I can use the [TestContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) to achieve the same thing.

Does anyone know if there is a "Collection Fixtures" equivalent for the MSTest framework?